# Story identification: Tiggewah's Web(?) in the universe

Tags: story-identification, novel

Does anyone remember a book where the main characters encounter something called the Tiggewah's Web (or something similar). I'm pretty sure my spelling is wrong though.

Back in the 70s, I read a book (I think it was "The God Makers") where everyone in the universe had a connection called 'Tiggewah's Web', and if someone died it was felt in the web, sorta like when an insect gets caught in a spider's web the spider knows it because of the vibrations the web sends to the spider.

When a person dies, a "spoke" is broken and, if one is in tune with the "web" (most aren't) one can feel it, similar to the Force in *Star Wars*. I remember there were some "monitors" of Earthlings and one of the monitors fell in love with and impregnated an Earth girl, and was the first of his kind to die, which shook up the "web".

Comment: There are two stories listed as "The God Makers" on ISFDB; one a space opera by Frank Herbert and the other a short story by R.Andrew Heigl (*a parable set among primitive fishermen who try to understand why one of their number is more successful than the rest, but which ends with their offering him in sacrifice*). Neither seem like a match

Comment: I researched before I asked the question, and none of those, as you found out, were satisfactory ... I remember there were some "monitors" of Earthlings and one of the monitors fell in love with and impregnated an earth girl, and was the first of his kind to die, which shook up the "web" ...

Comment: @Morgus Orson Scott Card's "Ender Saga" also has a concept of "philotes", subatomic strings which connect every living being in the universe.

Answer (score 8):

The book is [The Heaven Makers](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?852) by Frank Herbert, so you were very close.

The web is Tiggywaugh's web. The person who dies is Kelexel:

> Fraffin sighed, shuddered. The blurred-off moment of Kelexel's death had come to him through Tiggywaugh's web, the Chem oneness momentarily shattered by that impossible demarcation. Feeling that death, sensing its direction, Fraffin had known the identity with terrifying sureness. Every Chem in the universe had felt it, of course, and turned in this direction, no doubt, but Fraffin knew that few had shared his certain knowledge of identity. It was as though he'd anticipated the event.

Comment: Nicely done. Did you know this or did you search it out?

Comment: @Valorum: bit of both. The nagging feeling of *I'm sure I know this* finally drove me to search for it thoroughly. It only took me two years :-)

Comment: Thank you for the reply confirming something I had long sought ... now to eBay to get the book ... I wish you well ... Jon

Comment: @Morgus: if this is the answer you wanted please will you click on the tick symbol to accept the answer.